# linux - paste most similar historical command

Tags: linux, ubuntu, rhel

I remember there is some command which allows you to select most preferred historical commands to the terminal. That is something separte to history | grep or tail. I appreciate if you remind me it

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

See [this tutorial](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/08/bash-history-expansion/) on "history expansion" features (i.e. the `^` and `!` characters).

Comment: Thank you, yep, I know that commands :) The command I'm trying to remember is pasting preferred historical commands on the fly, so it's very convenient

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not exactly what you're looking for but close & useful nonetheless...

In a bash shell you can press `Ctrl+r` which puts you into a reverse history search mode.  Once in this mode start typing a command it will auto fill you most recent history that matches.  Repeatedly pressing `Ctrl-r` will cycle through all of the commands executed in that shell that match the particular pattern you have entered.